# Authentication service - Not able to implement

Tags: angular

Trying to implement authentication with the application. I tried to implement a fake authentication service using interceptors. But whenever I login I get the below error

posts:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
XHR failed to load: POST "http://localhost:4200/api/authenticate".

I tried to take the example from here http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Fake backend

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, 
HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, mergeMap, materialize, dematerialize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let testUser = { id: 1, username: 'test', password: 'test', firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'User' };
    console.log("**************************************************");
    // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
    return of(null).pipe(mergeMap(() => {

        // authenticate
        if (request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && request.method === 'POST') {
            if (request.body.username === testUser.username && request.body.password === testUser.password) {
                // if login details are valid return 200 OK with a fake jwt token
                let body = {
                    id: testUser.id,
                    username: testUser.username,
                    firstName: testUser.firstName,
                    lastName: testUser.lastName,
                    token: 'fake-jwt-token'
                };
                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body }));
            } else {
                // else return 400 bad request
                return throwError({ error: { message: 'Username or password is incorrect' } });
            }
        }

        // get users
        if (request.url.endsWith('/posts') && request.method === 'GET') {
            // check for fake auth token in header and return users if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
            if (request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: [testUser] }));
            } else {
                // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                return throwError({ error: { message: 'Unauthorised' } });
            }
        }

        // pass through any requests not handled above
        return next.handle(request);

    }))

    // call materialize and dematerialize to ensure delay even if an error is thrown (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648)
    .pipe(materialize())
    .pipe(delay(500))
    .pipe(dematerialize());
}
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
// use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
multi: true

};
```

login component

```
`
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {FormGroup,FormControl, Validators,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/first';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error = '';

  constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  // reset login status
  this.authenticationService.logout();

  // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

 onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }

  this.loading = true;
  this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
          data => {
              this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          },
          error => {
              this.error = error;
              this.loading = false;
          });
  }
}
```

`

App module

```
`
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from 'src/app/products.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
 import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/products.service';
import { DescriptionPipe } from 'src/app/description.pipe';
import { FavouriteComponent } from './favourite/favourite.component';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';
 import { NewcourseformcomponentComponent } from './newcourseformcomponent/newcourseformcomponent.component';
 import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateEditComponent } from 'src/app/create-edit/create-edit.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

 // used to create fake backend
 import { FakeBackendInterceptor } from 'src/app/helper/fake-backend';
import { ErrorInterceptor} from 'src/app/helper/error.interceptor';
import { JwtInterceptor} from 'src/app/helper/jwt.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppComponent,ProductsComponent, ProductComponent,DescriptionPipe, FavouriteComponent, 
PanelComponent, InputFormatDirective, ContactFormComponent, SignupFormComponent, NewcourseformcomponentComponent, 
PostsComponent, NavbarComponent, HomeComponent, NotfoundComponent, CreateEditComponent, AdminComponent, LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent },
     //     {path: 'posts/:id ', component: CreateEditComponent },
     {path: 'posts/:id/:title', component: CreateEditComponent },
     { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
     { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
     {path: 'posts', component: PostsComponent },
     {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
      ])

      ],
  providers: [

    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

       // provider used to create fake backend
    FakeBackendInterceptor],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

`

Authentication service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class AuthenticationService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`/api/authenticate`, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', 
JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        }));
 }

logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
}
```

}

Comment: you are doing a POST on `/posts` but your interceptor expects a GET: `if (request.url.endsWith('/posts') && request.method === 'GET')`. Either request the posts as GET or change the interceptor

Comment: I changed the code to actual i was trying out options

Comment: i think your app.module is wrong, your interceptor is probably not called at all, you have `FakeBackendInterceptor` in your providers. That is the class, but you need to inject it with the Token like the other interceptors, from the example, you just need to use `fakeBackendInterceptor` (first letter is lower case), that is the export from the bottom of the interceptor class `export let fakeBackendProvider = {...`. See your example link under `Angular 6 App Module`

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I did not help same error post the change in app module

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngxMocks

- Run `git clone https://github.com/abdelrahman-haridy01/ngx-mocks` for clone a repo.
- Then run `npm i` on project path after install all packages
- run `npm start`.Navigate to http://localhost:4200/. The app will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.
- Use http://localhost:3000/ for check Defualt API's by **getpostman**. Also You can check defualt API's in server/api.json path.

**Also Check the Documentation** https://github.com/abdelrahman-haridy01/ngx-mocks/blob/master/README.md